# View a table with a lot of columns (50)

Tags: excel, data-visualization

I was wondering if you know some tools to help to display a table with around 50 columns. Let's imagine we have 4 row and 50 columns:

- if we use Excel and dezoom we can't see anything,

so I was thinking of an interactive tool which dynamically displays the first columns on the screen and returns to line to display the remaining columns (perhaps it would need 5 or more return to lines to display all columns).

Do you know if such a tool (or tips to achieve this) exist?

Thanks

Comment: Do you know how to freeze panes? I think that's what you're after.

Comment: If the file is in csv or text format, you may use something like notepad, notepad++ or sublime text etc. to open the file and use wrap text. That should do what you need.

Comment: Could you upload a screenshot to have an idea of how many columns will you block and how many should be visible at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code on your sheet (Just change the name of your workbook, in my case Book1)

```
Range("F3").Select
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
ActiveWindow.NewWindow
Windows.CompareSideBySideWith "Book1:1"
Windows.SyncScrollingSideBySide = False
ActiveWindow.Zoom = 84
Windows("Book1.xlsm:2").Activate
Windows.SyncScrollingSideBySide = True
```

On a resolution of 1920x1080 pixels, you will get 50 columns on 2 windows synchronized.

Hope it helps